# Yehareg v'al yaavor by brain death

Tags: halacha, murder, yehareg-val-yaavor, brain-death, life

One must submit to death rather than murder another based on the equivalent value of all lives.

There's much debate about if brain death qualifies as death in halacha.

My question relates to if one takes the position that it is not death does that include a case where one is told to kill a brain dead person on pain of death (life is life) or does it stop short of that for some reason (less of a life etc)?

Comment: That's roughly the argument here https://www.academia.edu/51775521/BRAIN_DEATH_AND_ORGAN_DONATION_AN_ALTERNATIVE_CONSTRUCTION_OF_THE_DEBATE but it's a pretty novel idea

Comment: Relatedly, would capital punishment apply if one willfully murders a brain dead person . .